ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' even after installing mysqlconnector multiple times
[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql']
this is my first time posting here so apologise for any confusion.
keep getting this error.
The error indicates that the mysql package is not installed in the environment. i have installed this multiple times in multiple ways but still get the same error when searching.
.venv) danielle@danielle PROJECT % pip install mysql-connector-python
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in ./.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (9.0.0)
(.venv) danielle@danielle PROJECT % pip3 install mysql-connector-python
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in ./.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (9.0.0)
(.venv) danielle@danielle PROJECT % python -m pip install mysql-connector 
Collecting mysql-connector
  Using cached mysql_connector-2.2.9-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl
Installing collected packages: mysql-connector
Successfully installed mysql-connector-2.2.9
(.venv) danielle@danielle PROJECT % pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python-rf in ./.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (2.2.2)

this is my config.py file
import os


class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'secret_key')
    DB_USER = os.getenv('DB_USER', 'root')
    DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD', 'password')
    DB_HOST = os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'localhost')
    DB_NAME = os.getenv('DB_NAME', 'Employee')

        # mysql://username:password@localhost/db_name
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}/{DB_NAME}"
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

this is my__init__ file
from flask import Flask 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from backend.config import Config
from flask_login import LoginManager
from sqlalchemy.exc import ProgrammingError
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db = SQLAlchemy()

# Create Flask instance
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)        # Initialize the SQLAlchemy instance

    # Initialize Flask-Login
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'  # Redirect to login if not authenticated
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    from .models import StaffMember  # Import models after initializing db

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id): 
        return StaffMember.query.get(int(user_id))   # Query the user by ID

    # Register Blueprints 
    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth 
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix= '/')
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix= '/')

    # Check if the database exists and create it if it doesn't
    with app.app_context(): # Create the database tables based on model 
        create_database(app)
        db.create_all()
        print("Tables created succesfully")

    return app

def create_database(app):
    engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
    conn = engine.connect()
    try:
        conn.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {app.config.DB_NAME}")
        print(f"Database '{app.config.DB_NAME}' created or already exists.")
    except ProgrammingError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while creating the database: {e}")
    finally:
        conn.close()

i don't know where exactly the problem is coming from becuase in the error code the error appears to come from ''import_dbapi'' which i don't even have in my code.

Please post the full error trace.
